# View controller before SWRevealViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a login View and when i push one button must be opened other View with a SWRevealViewController, how I do that? 
This is my code and don't go.

```
LoginViewController *LoginViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MenuViewController"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:LoginViewController animated:YES];
```

Sorry for my English...

Comment: show your storyboard and mention that which button u want to perform action

Comment: I create the button with that code         btnConectar = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        [btnConectar setTitle:@"Conectar" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        btnConectar.frame = CGRectMake(0,(frameScr.origin.y)+500, self.view.bounds.size.width, 50.0);
        btnConectar.layer.backgroundColor= [[UIColor orangeColor] CGColor];
        [btnConectar addTarget:self
                        action:@selector(Click:)
              forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]; and the code of a Action is -(IBAction)Click:(id)sender

Comment: ya fine bro ,if your using this button side menu -- self.navigationController pushViewController does not worked need to call SWLsegueforPUSH

Comment: if I write this code don't go too          LoginViewController *LoginViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MenuViewController"];
    [self.revealViewController SWLsegueforPUSH:LoginViewController animated:YES];

Comment: bro - I used swl in last 10 projects thats Y I asked if u show in correctly I will find the error